# Notification limitation on android wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

On the wear device I see that it **can only display 12 Notifications per app**. E.g., when I get around 20 new emails, the wear app only shows the recent 12 emails and not more than that.

Similarly, I wrote a wear app which throws notifications and even there it doesn't display more than 12 notifications, **any new notifications are queued  after that and doesn't get shown in the notification until the existing ones are cleared. So, at any given point a max of 12 notifications can only be shown.**

Is it googles android wear limitation?

Here is my code..

PhoneDataListener which receives the dataItems from the mobile app..

```
public class PhoneDataListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    private static final String TAG = "Listener-W";


    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {


        for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
            Log.v(TAG, "DataMap received on watch: " + DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem()).getDataMap());
            // Check the data type
            if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                // Check the data path
                String path = event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath();
                if (path.equals("/weardatapath")) {}
                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
                ArrayList<DataMap> dataItemsList = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getDataMapArrayList
                        ("dataMapItems");
                // Broadcast DataMap contents to wearable show in notification..
                if (dataItemsList != null && dataItemsList.size() > 0) {
                    // start service for each Item in the dataItemsList
                    for (DataMap dMapItem : dataItemsList) {
                        startNotificatioService(this, dMapItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void startNotificatioService(Context context, DataMap dataMap) {
        Log.w(TAG, "start Service to show notification...");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        intent.setAction(NotificationService.ACTION_NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(NotificationService.DATA_PARAM, dataMap.toBundle());
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

The NotificationService on the wear app which builds and throws the notification

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

    private final static String TAG = "NotificationService-W";

    public static final String ACTION_NOTIFICATION = "com.test.phonewearsample.action.NOTIFIY";
    public static final String DATA_PARAM = "dataMap";
    private final static String MY_GROUP_KEY = "myGroupKey";

    public NotificationService() {
        super("NotificationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
                final Bundle data = intent.getBundleExtra(DATA_PARAM);
                handleActionNotification(data);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleActionNotification(Bundle data) {
        // Display received data in UI

        int dataId = data.getInt(SharedConstants.EXTRA_MAIL_ID);
        Log.w(TAG, "###########DataItems############# :"+dataId);
        String name = data.getString(SharedConstants.WearMails.CONTACT_NAME);
        String number = data.getString(SharedConstants.WearMails.PHONE_NUMBER);
        String duration = data.getString(SharedConstants.WearMails.DURATION);
        Long uniqueVal = data.getLong(SharedConstants.EXTRA_UNIQUE_ID);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        style.bigText(number + "\n" + duration);


        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setStyle(style)
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Play On Phone",
                        NotificationUtil.getReplyPendingIntent(this, Integer.toString(dataId)))
                .setGroup(MY_GROUP_KEY)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 50, 100}) 
                .setSortKey(Long.toString(uniqueVal));

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(dataId, notification.build());
    }
}
```

**Please note that at a time it can only show 12 notifications for a group. Once I take a action and notification gets cleared the pending one comes in.**

Comment: If it is ok, can you post the code?

Comment: Do you need the complete code or only the part where I build and throw the notification?

Comment: Just the part where you build the notification should be good. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my question and have added the code.

Comment: I don't know about the limitations, but is this something you want? It may be better to compound the notifications in to one anyway.

Comment: My requirements is something like, if I get 20 new mails from different contacts on my mobile, I would like to show on wear as 20 new mails instead of only 12 new mails which gives a wrong info to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Reading about this, I think this is a defect in Android Wear devices which Google is currently working on. Here is a link you can look at: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=130689.  I think this issue is wearable-specific.